# UPDATE statement t-sql w/o knowing identity field name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that generates dynamic SQL which I call `EXEC()` on at the end to perform an `UPDATE` statement.  I'm using it to update different tables which have different field names for the identity column, i.e., `UserId`, `ProductId`, `ShoppingCartId`, etc.

I could just pass in the field name of the identity column via a parameter to the stored procedure, but I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically reference the identity column in an update statement.

EX:

```
UPDATE @TableName 
SET @ColumnName = @ColumnValue 
WHERE table_identity_field = @RowId
```

where `table_identity_field` is the identity column for that particular table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I could just pass in the field name of the identity column via a
>   parameter to the sproc, but I'm wondering if there's a way to
>   dynamically reference the identity column in an update statement.

You can use the `$IDENTITY` keyword to reference the identity column of a table:

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET ColumnName = @ColumnValue 
WHERE $IDENTITY = @RowId;
```